# How to save files(doc,image,etc.,) through Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am loading Html page to panel, in that html page html file(uploadfile) is there. when ever i upload some file(doc,image,etc.,) and save html button.. i want to save that file to project in SAVED_DOCUMENTS folder, and also that path to database..

```
$('input[type="file"]').each(function () {
                  completeids.push($(this).attr('id'));
                  completevalues.push($(this).attr('value'));
                  completetype.push('FILE');
                  completeselected.push('no');

              });
```

After finding the value of file i want to dump that to SAVED_DOCUMNETS folder...
can you give some suggestion to handle this..

Answer (score 2):

if you mean saving files on client side, this is not possible without a user action.

If you are talking about saving files on the server, then you should use the `<input type="file"` HTML element. You would then have access to the FileContent property which is an array of byte you can save as a file wherever you want.

In an MVC controller you can have something like this:

```
 public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
   using (Stream stream = file.InputStream)
   {
        // Save your stream to Disk or database as you need
   }

}
```

Comment: yes, am using input type="file", if you don't mine, can you give some sample code

Comment: Be aware that the parameter named file should match the input control name of your view.